# Pdf Signature Validation for Adobe Sign

Tags: c#, .net, adobe, digital-signature, abcpdf

I have a pdf file that is being signed by the Adobe Sign. However, i am not able to verify/validate the signature using the ABCPdf. I guess i am missing Root Certificate for that. How can i find root certificate for Adobe Sign. I have root certificate for all the other providers like Digicert, Global sign. Also, all the other signature providers are working fine.

```
if ((signature.Validate(collection)) && (!signature.IsModified))
        {
            isValid = true;
        }
        try
        {
            isValid = signature.Validate();
        }
        catch (WebSupergoo.ABCpdf11.Internal.PDFException)
        {
            return ESignedStatus.SignedTempered;
        }

        var certs = signature.GetCertificates();

        if (!signature.IsTrusted)
            return ESignedStatus.SignedUnverified;
        else if (!isValid)
            return ESignedStatus.SignedTempered;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your answer is here:
https://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/6-abcpdf.objects/signature/1-methods/validate.htm

> How does Adobe Reader validate a PDF document without certificate
> files?
>
> You may find that Adobe Reader does not need a list of certificate
> files to validate PDF documents. This is because Adobe Reader may use
> several built-in Public Key Infrastructure hierarchies to certify PDF
> documents:
>
> Certified Document Services (CDS) is a trust hierarchy that chains
> back to the Adobe Root Certification Authority (Adobe Root CA). Adobe
> Approved Trust List (AATL) is an extra list of CA certificates that
> Adobe Reader may download from Adobe periodically (for Adobe
> Reader/Acrobat 9 or later). The Windows Certificate Store. This is
> only true if Windows digital signature integration is enabled in
> Acrobat, which has not been the default since Acrobat 9. In order to
> validate a PDF document the same way Adobe Reader does, you need to
> use the same certificates it uses. This can be easily achieved by
> exporting the trusted identities from Adobe Reader to .cer format
> certificate files. (Note: CDS and AATL certificates are usually not in
> your Windows Certificate Store by default.).
>
> These then need to be placed in the Windows Certificate Store. For
> them to be trusted they need to be in one of the Trusted folder -
> Trusted People or Trusted Root Certification Authorities. Needless to
> say, adding items to these folders - particularly the latter - is a
> big deal and you must be very careful to ensure you know what you are
> doing.
>
> The Windows Certificate Store can be accessed by using
> System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store (examples
> below).

To export it from Acrobat / Acrobat Reader:
[image: Show Signature Properties]

[image: Show Signer's Certificates]

[image: Export]